# How to calculate x^2 in sympy gamma

Tags: python, django, sympy

I am very new to coding in Python and using the django.

My question: is it possible to calculate x^2 in sympy gamma?In my program x**2 is working but x^2 is not working.

**^** is not working.

my code is-

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from sympy import *
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import *
import sympy as sp

# Create your views here.

def index(request):

    if request.method == "POST":

        x = symbols('x')
        init_printing()
        transformations = (standard_transformations + (implicit_multiplication_application,))
        eq = parse_expr(request.POST['equ'], transformations=transformations)       
        sympifyy = latex(sympify(eq, evaluate=False))
        sympifyy1 = Eq(eq)
        derivative = latex(sp._eval_derivative(eq,x))
        integration = latex(sp.integrate(eq, x))
        # integration = integrate(eq, x)
        # pretty(latex(Integral(eq, x)),use_unicode=False)
        # print(pretty(Integral(sqrt(1/x), x), use_unicode=False))
        rootss = solve(eq)
        limits = limit(eq, x, 0)        
        seriess = latex(series(eq, x, 0, 10))

        data = {
            'Sympify' : sympifyy,
            'Sympify1' : sympifyy1,
            'Derivative' : derivative,
            'Integration' : integration,
            'Roots' : rootss, 
            'Limit' : limits,
            'Series' : seriess
            }

        return render(request, 'index.html', {'data':data})

    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

**Ex-when user gives input is working **(x**2+x+2)** but user give input **(x^2+x+2)** then error occurs

Comment: What have you tried already? Can you show us some code that defines your problem?

Comment: @Nick Martin  hey nick just check my edited code

Comment: *In my program x**2 is working but x^2 is not working* if it works why dont you go for it?

Comment: @ Yugandhar Chaudhari it's not a proper and easy way to end user.. That's why i m use this step and most of the website like sympy gamma, cymath allow this type of input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in SymPy's online [documentation](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/gotchas.html#two-final-notes-and) SymPy follows the Python standard, where `^` is used for **exclusive or** (Xor).

So, your statement that `^` is not working, is inaccurate. It only does something else as what you imagined it would do. Xor is a quite nasty function, as it is only defined for booleans, not for unlimited integers nor for non-integer types of numbers.

Therefore, in your call to `parse_expr` you might want to add `convert_xor` to the list of transformations, as in

```
transformations = standard_transformations + (implicit_multiplication_application,) + (convert_xor,)
```

This function explicitly transforms `^` to `**`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer seems quite simple. Just `.replace("^", "**")` your incoming equation.

```
eqn = request.POST['equ'].replace("^", "**")
eq = parse_expr(eqn, transformations=transformations)
```

Additionally, I think there's a mistake in your code, should it be:

```
derivative = latex(sp.diff(eq,x))
```